# implicit declaration of function 'pthread_create'

Tags: c

When I am running my C code in a Raspbian environment I keep receiving this from the terminal. I am trying to create multiple threads to run pwm on two io pins while having a third thread that checks to see if a key 'q' is pressed to quit the program. What does this Warning mean?

Comment: The warning basically meand that `'pthread_create'` hasn't been declared. Everytime you see this warning you absolutely must consider it as an error; don't think: "it's just a warning".

Comment: `-Werror` is your friend

Comment: Every undeclared function warning means you've either forgotten to include the relevant header or you've got a typo in the function name (or, if you work on multiple platforms, it might mean that you're using a function that's available on Platform A and not available on Platform B).  Treat it as an error — all the C standards that have been current in this millennium have required functions to be declared before they're used; sadly, not all compilers enforce this requirement without being prodded into doing so by appropriate options. Treat such warnings as errors (and use `-Werror` with GCC).

Comment: Note, too, that it is good idea to show an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  In this case, the problem is easily diagnosed without the code, but in general, code is necessary.

Answer (score 7):

You must include `pthread.h` header at the beginning of the file where you use pthread functions

```
#include <pthread.h>
```